# Journal editor asked for: main.tex that produces main pdf text with references, and a separate appendix.pdf with references. How would one do this?

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing

at the moment I have one main.tex file that contains the appendices. Since I need to refer to all of the tables from my appendices in my main.tex, just cutting out the appendices from the main.tex leaves me with question marks in my main.tex. As stated in the question, the editor asks me for main.tex that refers to all tables including the appendices' tables/figures. This main.tex should produce a main.pdf with references, and at the same time I need to submit appendices.pdf with references but no appendices.tex. I have no idea how to even start with this request. This is the basic structure of my main.tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
maxcitenames=2,  
maxbibnames=99,
giveninits=true,
style= authoryear,
language=english,   
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false,   
url=false,
isbn=false,   
doi=false,
eprint=false  
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{chapter1.bib}
\begin{document} 
\section{introduction} 
Section \ref{append:definition of s.h.c.} gives a thorough discussion of.............
\section{variable description} 
\printbibliography         

\clearpage 
\begin{appendices}
    \begin{subappendices}
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \setcounter{section}{0}
        \setcounter{subsection}{0}
        \setcounter{table}{0}
        \setcounter{figure}{0}
        \renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
        \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{A.2.\arabic{subsection}}
        \renewcommand{\thetable}{A.3.\arabic{table}}
        \renewcommand{\thefigure}{A.4.\arabic{figure}}
\section{Data Specifics}
\label{append:dataspecifics}
\end{subappendices}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

I would highly appreciate anyone's help with this, thanks.
Since I am not very good with Latex, I would appreciate as much detail as possible.

Comment: You can use the `xr` package to refer to labels from other documents

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the info in the following [link] (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf). It works great with Overleaf, I get done what I needed. However, the journal has its own Latex editor and when I upload all of my files and compile them online with that editor, I receive question marks for the appendices table and figure references in the main pdf document. I am not supposed to use .tex subdirectory files for the journal's online editor, so I am wondering what I should do next. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.